# Geometry problem (from national competition)

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Given right angled triangle $\triangle ABC$ with right angle at point C.

Let points $D, E$ lie on $AB$, such that $|BC|=|BD|$ and $|AC|=|AE|$.

Let point $F$ be orthogonal projection of point $D$ onto $AC$ and let point $G$ be orthogonal projection of point $E$ onto $BC$.

Prove $|DE|=|DF|+|EG|$.

[image: :]

What I've got so far:

EDIT: Had a picture here, but I removed it because it was incorrect and now I don't feel like making new one because the question is already answered.

How can I solve or approach this problem?

Comment: Just checking: Which national competition is this? (If it's on-going, this question should be closed until the contest concludes.)

Comment: It's from 17.3.2018 from Macedonia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the altitude from $C$ to $AB$ which cuts $AB$ at $X$. Then it is enough to prove that $DX=DF$. Say $\angle ABC = 2x$, then $$ \angle BDC = \angle DCB = 90-x$$ and so $\angle DCX = x$. Clearly we have $$\angle ACX = 90-\angle XCB = 2x,$$ so $\angle FCD = x$.

So triangles $FCD$ and $XDC$ are congurent (a.s.a.) and thus a conclusion.